# How to map through objects in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using the .map() function in the exact same way as in other projects, but on the one I am currently working on, it's throwing me this error: `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, title}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`
This is my code (the structure of which has worked in other projects as I mentioned):

```
import React from "react";
import Carousel from "react-elastic-carousel";

const Slider = () => {

  let items = [
    {id: 1, title: 'item #1'},
    {id: 2, title: 'item #2'},
    {id: 3, title: 'item #3'}
]

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Carousel>
          {items.map((item) => (
            <div key={item}>{item}</div>
          ))}
        </Carousel>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Slider;
```

I am wondering if it has to do with the fact that I am mapping inside of a component imported from an external library.

I have also tried adding an index to `.map(item, index)` and that didn't work either.

Comment: It has to do with the fact that you're trying to render an object (item is an object). I doubt that it would have worked in other projects.

Comment: Try searching for the error, Objects are not valid React nodes (see docs), you sure ment something like: `<div key={item.id}>{item.title}</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `item` is an object. You need to update like this:

```
<div key={item.id}>{item.title}</div>
```